# Why component rendered with ReactDOM.render loses react-redux context (Provider)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, provider

For example my application consists from 2 parts and is wrapped in `Provider`:

```js
<>
  <Provider store={store}>
     <ModalWindow />
     <Main />
  </Provider>
</>
```

I render different content in `ModalWindow`, for this I have config file:

```js
export const modalConfig = {
  firstConfig: {
    onRender: (node, props) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<FirstComponent {...props} />, node)
    },
  },
  secondConfig: {
    onRender: (node, props) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<SecondComponent {...props} />, node)
    },
  },
 }
```

My `Main` component has always react-redux context and I can use `useSelector` or `useDispatch`

But why components which I render with `ReactDOM.render()` don't have react-redux context?
I need to wrap them additional to solve this, like this:

```js
export const modalConfig = {
  firstConfig: {
    onRender: (node, props) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><FirstComponent {...props} /></Provider>, node)
    },
  },
  secondConfig: {
    onRender: (node, props) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><SecondComponent {...props} /></Provider>, node)
    },
  },
}
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Could you show the content <ModalWindow /> component content?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ReactDOM.render` to insert the modals into the document, so they wind up **outside** of the `Provider` component, which is rendered inside your root node (probably `document.getElementById("root")`).

I'm not sure why you need `ReactDOM.render` here.  You could probably redesign this so that `ModalWindow` just conditionally `return`s some content.  You can use CSS styling to make it into an overlay.  You can also look into the [React `Portal` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).