# Pass context when render components programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my REACT application, I'm trying to render a Component programmatically, but pasing to it any REACT context. Let me show you a simple example with this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-carson-u0hup?file=/src/App.tsx

As you can see, what I want to do is rendering `<Dialog>` programmatically when I click a button. But, inside that `<Dialog>`, I want to use any context created on the React Tree.
Unfortunately, I am aware that `React.render` does not pass any context, thus this cannot work: if you click on the button, you will see that, while the context in `<InnerComponent>` provides the value `'FooBar'`. inside `<Dialog>` I have the default value `'initialValue'`.

Thus, the question is, is there any way I can programmatically render a component, AND passing to its any kind of context?
I'm aware that `React.createPortal` does pass the context, but that method MUST be called inside the `return` statement of a component, while instead, in my case, I render the `<Dialog>` after a click on the Button.
Also, yes, I could always have the `<Dialog>` rendered, and use a prop `isVisible`.. But this is a simpler example.

I've read several things (some of these in the following links), but none of these really helped me:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17974
- [Is it possible to pass context into a component instantiated with ReactDOM.render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212174/is-it-possible-to-pass-context-into-a-component-instantiated-with-reactdom-rende)
- [Why component rendered with ReactDOM.render loses react-redux context (Provider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221206/why-component-rendered-with-reactdom-render-loses-react-redux-context-provider)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put the render of component outside of your ContextProvider.

Check this link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-curran-pbz6p?file=/src/App.tsx:0-834

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I literally wrote that I'm looking for a solution (if it exists) to render from outside the render.. And not a solution that includes having the `<Dialog>` in the return with some `isVisible` prop

Comment: React allows all child components to access the `ContextConsumer` but in your way the `<Dialog />` component won't recognize as a child component